# vba worksheet_change for pasting value from one sheet to another is not working, but works manually

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    If Intersect(target, Worksheets("SheetA").Range("V:V")) Is Nothing Then 
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        thisrow = target.Row
        Worksheets("SheetB").Cells(12, 1).Value = Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A" & thisrow).Value
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I am trying to populate SheetB's cell A12 under the condition that SheetA's Column V was triggered, and the value I am assigning SheetB A12 is the A&the row of the trigger.

However, I can't seem to get the code to work.

If someone can point out what's wrong with the code that would be great!
And I was wondering if anyone has tips on debugging subs like Workbook_SheetChange/ worksheet_change

**Edit:**

I posted my new code, instead of using workbook_sheetchange, I am trying worksheet_change.

It is still not working, however, when I run it manually it does work. And in the immediate window, I type "? Application.EnableEvents = True" and it returns true.

Comment: You didn't test for `ByVal Sh As Object`. Edit: you want `sheet_change` not `workbook_sheetchange`.

Comment: @findwindow Thanks for the feedback! I tried Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) first, and it didn't work. I can't run this in the immediate window to see where it is failing either

Comment: Please edit your OP with updated code.

Comment: @findwindow Hi, I just updated my question, hope it is clearer! Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There is something seriously off... There is an `End If`, but there is no block `If` statement... This code is not supposed to work at all.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. This goes in `SheetA`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, WorkSheets("A").Range("V:V")) Is Nothing Then

    'Application.EnableEvents = False

    thisrow = Target.Row
    Debug.Print thisrow

    WorkSheets("B").Cells(12, 1).Value = WorkSheets("A").Cells(thisrow, 1).Value

    'Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Edit: per vacip's comment.

Comment: `Target.column` is nice, but it is not the same as `Intersect(Target, range("v:v"))`. What if you update range("u1:z1")?

Comment: @vacip OP's condition was column V. Never said anything about updating range. And even if OP were to update range, `intersect` still would break. So not sure what you're trying to get at here.

Comment: Worksheet_Change runs every time a range - any range - is changed. Updated. This can be a single cell, in which case your code does the same as OP's. Or it can be several cells, in which case it is not the same. Is that more clear now?

Comment: No need to get defensive, I'm not saying what you did is wrong. I merely point out a small fact that seems to have eluded you.

Comment: Oh. Misunderstood what you meant when you said update. It makes sense that the two is different but I can't make the distinction in logic. But thanks, will play with it.